# The concept of control of flow rate

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Very often I have come across flow control valves being fitted in hydraulic circuits to control the flow rate, but I fail to understand as to how flow rate can be controlled.

Say for example the flow rate of hydraulic oil entering a flow control valve is $10 m^3/min$ and the flow rate exiting the valve is $8 m^3/min$. Which means if $10 m^3$ of oil is entering the valve, only 8 is coming out, i.e: there is an accumulation $2 m^3$ of oil?

is this a violation of law conservation of mass?

How do we explain the flow control technique?

Comment: The hydraulic fluid might be compressible; the density can change.

Comment: @Yaschas Samaga And for incompressible fluids? Also I'd think that hydraulic oil is most likely incompressible.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, incompressibility is a good assumption. Flow control can achieved in many ways. Reading your example, it seems  that flow control is being achieved by diverting some of the flow away from the main flow line by means of a bypass valve. Mass conservation is never violated.

Comment: How do you achieve flow control in flow control  valves used in hydraulic circuits?

Comment: @joey _You_ have to tell us what method was used in your particular example. What I have written is only a guess, albeit a good one, since oil cannot simply vanish into thin air.

Comment: I have not used any particular method of flow control.I just stated the facts of flow control technique.No matter what technique is used ,the input flow control  will be lesser than output...I am not able to understand this particular fact ?

Comment: @joey "No matter what technique is used ,the input flow control will be lesser than output..." That is incorrect. Take your bathroom tap for example. It controls flow of water, and input to tap exactly equals output from tap.

Comment: Exactly ....the upstream & downstream flow rates are always same & has to be same.If thats true then what are we controlling using a flow control valve??

Comment: @joey You are controlling the flow rate, period. Using control valve, output flow can be varied from zero to a maximum, and input flow follows suit.

Comment: To add to @Deep answer. Flow control is often achieved by controlling the pump, i.e. with a bypass as mentioned. The "excess" flow is then diverted. Another possibility I could think of would be that an almost closed valve results in a pressure drop, therefore with a constant power to the pump the flow rate decreases $P = Q \Delta p$ with a higher pressure drop and constant power the flowrate Q decreases. As deep mentioned without a detailed setup from you this is guess work. You cannot simply state violation of mass consv. without regarding a specific setup.